# Html thumbnail gallery java code

Tags: java, html, image, gallery, thumbnails

I would like to generate html code for an image gallery consisting of thumbnails in Java. There are a great many scripts out there that do this, mostly in php or perl, and quite a few standalone, but I have not found any Java library or code that can do this. This is for a Java application.
Is anyone aware of a java library package or source code that can do this?

Any pointers appreciated.

Andy

Comment: Could you elaborate on your question. Where is this image gallery? Why can't you write code in a JSP with a for loop to create html code for the same?

Comment: This is a standalone Java application, its a not an applet, and its not running on a webserver. The html gallery would be viewed in a browser inside the application, but not necessarily published online, although the user may later choose to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the ideal use case for [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) . You will have to have a look at [XSL-FO](http://www.w3schools.com/xslfo/default.asp). Also look at the answer given to [an earlier question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743942/using-xsl-fo-and-html) . Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I really can not understand how that can help me. I need html code for a gallery with a set of pictures as input. Could you explain?